# AS3: hitTestObject vs hitTestPoint for Bullet vs Enemy

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have been following the discussion of hitTestObject vs hitTestPoint vs custom hitTest for quite some time. Often I have gone down the route of using Point, given the shape option.

However - I am now trying to do a hit test of a bullet hitting a circular enemy. What I am currently using is below:

[image: hit test]

```
for (var i:int = 0; i<levelHolder.enemyArray.length; i++){
            if(levelHolder.enemyArray[i]){
                if(this.hitTestObject(levelHolder.enemyArray[i].hit) && hit == false && distanceTravel <= range){
                    trace("You hit a baddie "+i)
                    hit = true
                    this.parent.removeChild(this)
                    var gotShot:gotshot = new gotshot() // move to sound
                    gotShot.play()                      // move to sound
                    levelHolder.damageEnemy(i, damage)
                } 
            }   
        }
```

Now, obviously this is causing the bullet to stop in the alpha areas around the hit and count it as a hit.

I did assume that I would be able to easily do the following, however it does not work:

```
if(this.hitTestPoint(levelHolder.enemyArray[i].x, levelHolder.enemyArray[i].y, true) && hit == false && distanceTravel <= range)
...
```

This causes a very, very limited hit range as we're working with the single X and Y position.

My question is this: How can I do this with more accurancy?

Comment: I should mention that this hitTest is within bullet1.as

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing noticed is this, if you talk about performence the code below failed. Single change on it will give performence like %90

```
if(this.hitTestObject(levelHolder.enemyArray[i].hit) && hit == false && distanceTravel <= range)
// this way is much better.
if( hit == false && distanceTravel <= range && this.hitTestObject(levelHolder.enemyArray[i].hit))
```

Second thing is to implement your own hit test as @Russel says, if you are working with circles. And try not to use Math.sqrt() function.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming bullets and baddies are always circular, you could either...

1. Use hitTestPoint, with the hit object for the enemy being a circle with its radius increased by the radius of the bullet, or
2. Implement the hit test yourself by checking whether the distance between the centers of the two objects is larger than the sum or their radii.

Comment: I think the majority of my problem comes from not fully understanding how to work hitTestPoint. If I am only allowed to specify one X and one Y position, how is it meant to be able to check all around the circular enemy?

Answer (score 0):

Hit tests for two circular objects can easily be done using something like this.

```
var dx:Number = a.centerX - b.centerX;
var dy:Number = a.centerY - b.centerY;
var dLimit = a.radius + b.radius;
return Square(dx) + Square(dy) <= Square(dLimit);
```

Sorry if  went a bit Psudocode, but I think that is relatively clear.